# pandoc: `RawBlock` in filter

Tags: pandoc, pypandoc

What is the correct use of the `RawBlock` function in Pandoc filters?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Str, Para, Emph, Header, RawBlock
import re

def replace(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'Str':
        if value.startswith('Hello'):
            #return Str("Hi")  # this works
            return RawBlock("opendocument", "Hi")  # this doesn't

if __name__ == '__main__':
    toJSONFilter(replace)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to replace an *Inline* value (`Str`) with a *Block* value (`RawBlock`).  One can only replace elements with elements of the same type. Use `RawInline` instead of `RawBlock`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, which leads to the expected output. It is actually quite obvious, if one thinks about it.